# XHTML - What's the advantage of using xhtml in modern application development?

Tags: html, xhtml

I've found a website that use `xhtml`extension for pages. [I'm reading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xhtml-introduction/) about this standard and I want to give it a try. Is there any advantage by using it instead of `HTML5`? Is this standard compatible with bootstrap, vuejs and other framework available out there?

Comment: I'd say the only time XHTML really comes into its own is when you're embedding HTML snippets into a larger XML document. Then obviously, to maintain the XML compatibility, using the HTML syntax is not suitable. But if using XHTML at all, always use the XML syntax of HTML5, and not XHTML 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

True XHTML, even in its HTML5 form XHTML5, is not compatible with many frameworks because they use non-standard elements and attributes that don't validate as XHTML.

Most developers consider the original XHTML 1 old tech these days, reserved only for specialized use cases. XHTML5 is simply HTML5 with an XHTML coat of paint. And the vast majority of XHTML sites that *don't* use the .xhtml extension are really HTML pretending to be XHTML anyway. Granted, true XHTML does help you write standards-compliant markup, but the way it does that is by *refusing to render any page that has even a single syntax error* (typo, missing attribute quotes, missing end tag, etc). My advice to you is to stick to HTML5 — its language rules are far more relaxed and you'll have a much easier time authoring it than XHTML.

Comment: It's not really a validity thing. Element and attribute validity in both syntaxes of HTML5 is _almost_ identical. XML syntax compliance is another matter and it's certainly true that some frameworks and libraries have issues. For creating XHTML oneself though, I've never really understood the issue with syntax well-formedness. Any decent XML editor will tell you if you're going astray there, and many people write plenty of XML that works just fine.