# Does CSS use token or substring algorithm when processing selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      .square__element {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: orange;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="square__element">Square 1</div>
    <div class="square__element--modifier">Square 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And when I run it none of the styles declared in the *.square__element{}* **selector** was applied to the "*Square 2*" **element**.
Initially I thought that "Square 2" element should have all the styles declared in the .square__element{} selector been applied to it. That's why I googled for a number of search queries trying to figure out whether that was me having wrong expectations, or whether my browser was glitching. But I found nothing helpful.

Then I opened w3c and studied the specification for around an hour. I went through the whole "Syntax" chapter but didn't find the answer either.

And, as the last mean, I asked all AI chats I had in my disposal.
Thee of them ( Bard, Chat GPT and Copilot) told me that the styles declared in the .square__element{} **should have been applied** to the "Square 2" element because

> "The CSS processor uses a substring matching algorithm"

However Bing chat told that the styles **should not** have been applied unless I have `<div class="square__element square__element--modifier">Square 2</div>` separated by space because

> "The CSS processor does not use a substring matching algorithm, but a
> token matching algorithm, where a token is a sequence of characters
> that are not spaces, tabs, line breaks, or other separators. "

So, I'm still do not know the correct answer.
Could anybody please help me to figure out should or should not the rules declared in the .square__element{} selector have been applied to the "Square 2" element?
Maybe pointing me to where in the specification I missed it explained.

Comment: This is the problem with asking LLMs answers to programming questions; they don't actually know the answer, they just string together words that might be an answer. `square__element` is the whole and unique class name, as is `square__element--modifier`. The fact that they share some characters in common is irrelevant to the CSS processor.

Comment: It's like expecting all elements with `class="button"` to have styles declared as `.u {}`. What a mess that would be!

Comment: thank, you! 
I thought the same way. Maybe you could point me to where in the specification, if not to an exact paragraph, but at least to a chapter or a section, from where I could learn why the css processor works that way? I mean why it doesn't use the substring algorithm, but the token one when telling the difference between the selectors.

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Don't worry about the closing slash. You could remove it if you want, but you could also leave it in for readability. It's really not a big deal.

Comment: @Rob Don't you mean, "for all HTML [*void* tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element)"? Other tags most certainly do need one; in their closing tag, of course ;) Note that they *are* required in XML, XHTML, and SVG; of which that last one is relevant to many web developers.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Of course closing tags need one. XML, XHTML and SVG are not HTML. This question is about HTML. My point is, don't write markup that does nothing, has no meaning, is ignored and the standard doesn't say to use them.

Comment: @BoltClock I have no clue how adding a closing slash aids readability. Nobody ever put that in before until they started mixing it up with XHTML.  I believe there are only seven self-closing tags. If one stumbles over that....well.....

Comment: @Rob I just mentioned it for clarity, as someone with less experience may be confused by the statement that 'HTML tags do not use closing slashes'.  I mentioned SVG because inline SVG will require them, and some people like the consistency of just always using them. MDN lists 14 void elements, but some of them are less used/more obscure.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, but I suppose there is a reason it carried back over to modern-day HTML. While that's not to say I think most people know or care to understand the history of why it's there or why it's not actually needed or functional, enough people have said it does help them distinguish void elements that I've learned not to question it anymore. It's just one of those weird things in life, I guess.

Comment: @Rob: Check out some of my older ramblings about HTML/XHTML markup and void elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871965), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25314415) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66899104). Some of them might be familiar to you, but it's been so long.

Comment: @BoltClock I am positive the only reason they put it there is because they see it done elsewhere and no other reason. They have not read or understood the standard but, once they find out, they will find any excuse to continue to do so. Once again, it's a pointless and useless practice that the W3C, WHATWG and MDN all complain about and why I--and we--should always point out to people.

Answer (score 2):

No it shouldn't. Both `square__element` and `square__element--modifier` are two **different** [valid class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors).

Adding a modifier like this is usually just a **naming convention** saying that the modifier is changing appearance or behavior to the base class (`square_element`). Hence, the modifier class itself shouldn't be use alone. You can see many similar examples in [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) classes like this such as `btn btn-lg` where `btn-lg` makes `btn` looks bigger.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703546/what-is-bem-methodology) explains pretty well what is a BEM (Block Element Modifier) naming convention and how could they be implemented.

Comment: thank, you, Synd.
I thought the same way. Maybe you could point me to where in the specification, if not to an exact paragraph, but at least to a chapter or a section, from where I could learn why the css processor works that way? I mean why it doesn't use the substring algorithm, but the token one when telling the difference between the selectors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its implementation depends on which browser you are using. For example Chrome uses (or at least was using) Blink, and Firefox uses a different rendering engine. These engines are the one that are doing the CSS Parsing.  I don't know what algorithms they are using, and I'm not sure if there are specs for how parsing algorithm should be implemented.

Comment: For `token parsing algorithm` vs `substring parsing algorithm`, I've no clue what a `substring parsing algorithm` is and where did Bing got this name but most langauge parsers parse strings into tokens simply because [there are many benefits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/240255/what-is-the-responsibility-or-benefit-of-a-tokenizer).

Comment: CSS Processors work that way because they follow the [CSS specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#class-html). The specs state that the class selector is identical to `[class~=val]`, which "Represents an element with the attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is **exactly** "val"."

Comment: 'whitespace-separated' that is what I supposed it should be. I believe the paragraph 6.1 "Attribute presence and value selectors" of the page is what I needed. Thank you, Duroth.

Comment: @SyndRain, maybe Bing took the 'substring parsing' from the section [6.2 "Substring matching attribute selectors"] (https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings) of the spec.

Comment: @Redgard Maybe! This spec is more like describing the intended matching rules, not how they should implement the parsing/matching. Bing is mixing them up. I doubt the spec will have implementation level specifications.

Answer (score 1):

CSS uses token-based parsing ([css-syntax-3§3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#tokenizing-and-parsing)), matches each class name as an [ident](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#consume-ident-like-token) ([selectors§6.6](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#class-html)) separated by spaces, and considers all of `square__element--modifier` a single ident token distinct from `square__element` because the double dashes form part of an ident ([css-syntax§4.3.11](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#consume-name), [§4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#ident-code-point)):

> ***ident-start code point***
> A letter, a non-ASCII code point, or U+005F LOW LINE (_).
>
> ***ident code point***
> An ident-start code point, a digit, or U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (-).

In other words, `.square__element` doesn't match `square__element--modifier` because they are two different class names. The double dashes count as part of the class name. It has nothing to do with "substring matching", whatever the AI thinks that means. As Heretic Monkey said,

> This is the problem with asking LLMs answers to programming questions; they don't actually know the answer, they just string together words that might be an answer.